# Are there hooks for Windows Updates?

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, snapshot

It would be really neat to be able to attach a "blocking hook" to when a Windows Update gets installed so that I could take a snapshot on an ESXi of the machine in question before the update is installed.

In Windows I would imagine that you'd attach it to some kind of event ID in task scheduler, but I don't think it would "block" so that the snapshot happens before the update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a signal is sent to the system, which can be intercepted, as in the case of shutdown (WM_ENDSESSION) for example, or a event you can get from the log BEFORE the update is launched.

You could very crudely do a scheduled (batch) search for updates.
If they exist, take a snapshot and then apply them.
Really crude.
There is a (not free) software that do this kind of stuff, but I don't think it is permissible to mention it

From Windows 10-1803 yes, you can (maybe!)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-enable-custom-actions

Comment: I think that's for when you're setting up Windows with a silent installer.